# How to get the derived class name in the base class (Angular2+)?

Tags: angular

When I have a class that extends a base class, how can I get the name of the derived class (in the base class)?

I have a method in the base class that is called by the derived classes; I want to know which instance is calling that method; with *this.constructor.name* I have the current base class, not the derived one.

Angular 4/5

Thanks.

[Update]

- I'm calling the function in the base class using both **this**.funcInBaseClass() and **super**.funcInBaseClass().
- the function is "protected"

Comment: Sorry for asking: why do you want to know the name of the class?

Comment: I have a provider that is used by many components, it is called too many times andf I want just monitor/find which component is doing the "extra" call. A sort of debug, I don't base logic on the component "name".

Comment: The constructor name appears to work for me. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-problem-databinding-n6mbyy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use name property of Constructor Class.

```
class Base {   
    public process(value: any) {
        alert(this.constructor["name"]); // alerts 'Derived' in this example
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public process(value: any) {
        super.process(value); // use super to call methods on the base class
    }
}

(new Derived).process('someValue');
```